# 'Cannot find type 'GIDSignIn' in scope' - Can't figure out how to resolve this issue in my Xcode/Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am a newbie hobby developer trying to learn to code by building a somewhat simple iOS app in Swift/Xcode. I am using Google Sign In with Firebase Auth to authenticate users (Sign-In With Google button), and am using Firebase and Firestore for the data.

I had the Google Sign In working in Simulator but for whatever reason it stopped working. Even though I have added the necessary package through Swift Package Manager and triple checked all of the plist settings, and made sure that I am, as far as I know, correctly importing GoogleSignInSwift on the appropriate files, I can't get past the "Cannot find type 'GIDSignIn' in scope" error.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

I have tried deleting the package and reinstalling, cleaned build folder, deleted derived data, closed and re-opened x-code many times.